# Is this expression for the Laplacian of conformal maps between Riemannian manifolds known?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, conformal-geometry, regularity

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}$
$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$
$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$
$\newcommand{\TM}{\operatorname{T\M}}$
$\newcommand{\TN}{\operatorname{T\N}}$
$\newcommand{\sAverage}[1]{\langle#1\rangle} $
$\newcommand{\IP}[2]{\sAverage{#1,#2}}$
$\newcommand{\Cof}{\text{Cof}}$

Lately I derived the following equation (details are at the end):

> **Theorem:**
>     Let $(\M,g),(\N,h)$ be smooth $d$-dimensional oriented Riemannian manifolds,
>
> Let $\,f:\M \to \N\,$ be a smooth conformal map. Then
>
> $$ \det df \cdot  \delta(df) + (\frac{2}{d}-1)     \tr_{g}\big(df \otimes d \det(df)  \big) =0. \tag{1} $$

($\delta$ is the adjoint of the pullback connection on $f^*{\TN}$. The equation is an equality of sections of $f^*{\TN}$.)

*Equation $(1)$ has a few immediate (well-known) corollaries:*

1. In dimension $d=2$, conformal mappings are harmonic.
2. Homotheties are harmonic (in every dimension).
3. In dimension $d > 2$, conformal harmonic maps are homotheties (assuming $\M$ is connected): 
   Let $e_i$ be an orthonormal frame for $\TM$. Then  $$ 0=\tr_{g} \big( df \otimes d \det(df) \big)= \sum_{i=1}^d  d \det(df)(e_i) \cdot df(e_i) .$$
   Since $f$ is an immersion, $df(e_i)$ is a basis of $f^*\TN$.

(Summary: A conformal map is harmonic if and only if $d=2$ or it is a homothety).

**Questions:**

**1.** Is equation $(1)$ known? (Perhaps in a Euclidean setting? Or in coordinates?)

**2.** Is equation $(1)$ an Euler-Lagrange's equation of some functional?

---

*Sketch of derivation:*

My colleagues and I showed the following:

> **Theorem(2):**
>     Let $(\M,g),(\N,h)$ be smooth $d$-dimensional oriented Riemannian manifolds,
>
> Let $\,f:\M \to \N\,$ be an **arbitrary** smooth map. Then
>
> $$ \delta (\Cof df)=0. \tag{2}$$ 
>   where $\Cof df:= (-1)^{d-1} \star_{f^*TN}^{d-1} (\wedge^{d-1} df) \star_{TM}^1.$ (It's a section  of $T^*\M \otimes f^*{\TN}$).

(For a proof see Proposition 3.4 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08892v1.pdf)).

Now, if $f$ is conformal, then
$$ \Cof df=(\det df)^{1-\frac{2}{d}} df. \tag{3}$$

Plug $(3)$ into $(2)$  (the rest is Leibniz rule + simplification).

Comment: A couple of quick comments: 1) If you pull back the metric on $\mathcal{N}$ back to $\mathcal{M}$, then $f$ becomes effectively the identity map and your equations become equations for the conformal metric. Those probably can be found in the literature. However, I always prefer writing such equations the way you have. 2) You can probably prove a regularity result. Work in this direction, I believe, can be found in papers discussing quasiconformal maps. A random paper that comes to mind is one by Donaldson and Sullivan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, *for conformal maps* equation $(1)$ is merely $d$-harmonicity in disguise:)

The equation is
$$
\delta\big((\det df)^{1-\frac{2}{d}} df\big)=0. \tag{1}
$$

Since for conformal maps, $\det df=\|df\|^d$ up to a constant, we equivalently get

$$
\delta\big(\|df\|^{d-2} df\big)=0. \tag{2}
$$

(Which is trivial of course, since conformal maps are source symmetries of the $d$-energy).

The funny part is that while  equation $(2)$ is an Euler-Lagrange's equation, equation $(1)$ is **not** (for $d \neq 2$).

The moral here is that if we start from an E-L equation, write it differently for specific class of maps (the conformal maps in this example) then the resulted equation may not be an E-L equation.

*Let's prove equation $(1)$ is not E-L:*

Indeed, if it were an E-L equation (of an isometrically invariant smooth functional), this would imply the existence of a smooth map $ h:M_d \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $dh_X(V)=\langle (\det X)^r X,V\rangle $.

This is not possible since $d^2h\neq 0$:

$d^2h=\sum_{ij}(\det X)^rx_{ij}dx^{ij} \Rightarrow d^h=\sum_{ijks} \frac{\partial((\det X)^rx_{ij}) }{\partial x_{sk}} dx^{sk} \wedge dx^{ij}=r \sum_{ijks} x_{ij} \frac{\partial \det X }{\partial x_{sk}} dx^{sk} \wedge dx^{ij}$ which is zero iff 
$$x_{ij} \frac{\partial \det X }{\partial x_{sk}} =x_{sk} \frac{\partial \det X }{\partial x_{ij}} , $$ which is false. (The RHS does not depend on $x_{ij}$ while the LHS is dependent of it).